# Euler's formula using probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For $s > 1$, define the zeta function by
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n^{−s}$$
Fix $s > 1$, and let $X$ be a random variable with $P(X = n) = n^{−s}/\zeta(s)$.

1) Show that the events $\{p \text{ divides } X \text{ s.t. } p \text{ is prime} \}$ are independent and deduce Euler’s formula
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_{p: \ p \ \text{prime}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right).$$

2) Prove also that
$P(X \text{ is square-free}) = \dfrac{1}{\zeta (2s)}$

3) Let $Y$ be an independent copy of $X$ and let $G$ be the greatest common divisor of $X$ and $Y$ .
Show that
$P(G = n) = \dfrac{n^{−2s}}{\zeta(2s)}$.

[$X$ is square-free = No perfect square other than $1$ divides $X$.]

I have been able to show (1) and (2). How to go about with (3)?

Comment: This is solved here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908405/probability-of-highest-common-factor-in-williams?rq=1